# Updating multiple rows on a spreadsheet based on userform selection

Tags: vba, combobox, textbox, userform

Just a quick query, I'm looking to update multiple rows in a database using a Userform. I want it to search column B by Combobox1 and update column D with the value in textbox 4.

Below is the code I have which isn't performing the task I want:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1. PO tracker")

For i = sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 13

If sh.Range("B" & i).Value = Me.ComboBox1 Then
sh.Range("D" & i).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value

End If

Next I
```

Can anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `For i = sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 13` - if there are more than 13 rows in column C, the `FOR` loop will be skipped as the number of rows will exceed 13.  I'm guessing that's now what you mean to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael, however this line of code still doesn't work. It doesn't update column D at all.